# changing click state with a variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a distinct feeling that i'm going about this the wrong way.

What i have is a list of hyperlinks, each of the hyperlinks when clicked run through a short sequence and are left in a different state, and if you click them again, revert to the original state.

```
var favourites = function(action, trgt){
var state = 0
$(trgt).on(action, function(e){
    if(state === 0){
        state = 1;
        thistrgt = $(e.currentTarget);
        thistrgt.css('opacity', '0.6');
        thistrgt.removeClass('favourites');
        thistrgt.addClass('favouriteschangestate');
        thistrgt.text('Saving to favourites');
        setTimeout(function(){
            thistrgt.css('opacity', '1');
            thistrgt.text('Saved!');
            setTimeout(function(){
                thistrgt.text('Remove from favourites');
            },2000);
        }, 2000);
    }else if(state === 1){
        state = 0;
        thistrgt = $(e.currentTarget);
        thistrgt.css('opacity', '0.6');
        thistrgt.removeClass('favouriteschangestate');
        thistrgt.addClass('favourites');
        thistrgt.text('Removing from favourites');
        setTimeout(function(){
            thistrgt.css('opacity', '1');
            thistrgt.text('Removed!');
            setTimeout(function(){
                thistrgt.text('Add from favourites');
            },2000);
        }, 2000);
    }
    return false;
});

}
// fire
favourites('click', '.favourites');
```

the second state is an attempt to revert the click back to its original state.

at the moment, each of the links are firing separately but there's a host of problems; the first being that the if statement is failing and the inks just fire the same bit again. the second is that if i fire the links too quickly in succession they break and lock up.

here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GZtM/1/)

thanks

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. You should be using attr. I have posted the answer below along with the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your code, use `ternary operators (?:)` to define your texts, states...
Store the current state into a `data-*` property as boolean and reuse it to define your states:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9GZtM/11/)**

```
var favourites = function (action, trgt) {
    $(trgt).one(action, function oneClick(e) { // one to prevent multiple clicks
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(e.target),       
            dS = $this.data('state');    
        $this.data('state', !dS)               // toggle and store data state
           .css('opacity', '0.6')
           .toggleClass('favouriteschangestate favourites')
           .text(dS? 'Removing from favourites':'Saving to favourites');       
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.text(dS? 'Removed!':'Saved!');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.css('opacity', '1')
                     .text(dS? 'Add to favourites':'Remove from favourites')
                     .one('click',oneClick);   // allow click again
            }, 2000);
        }, 2000);
    });
};

// fire
favourites('click', '.favourites');
```

Also read:
 http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: how would i go about disabling the link after it's clicked, preventing the user from reverting it before the sequence has completed?

Comment: @RussellSims by simply using a named `.one()` function Method instead of `.on()` take a look at the edited example above.

Answer (score 0):

well, the main problem here is that you're setting the state to 0 when you click.
move it up out of the .on()

Comment: thanks, i've updated the fiddle, but now the problem it's suffering from is it's continuing to the second state on links that haven't been click yet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/9GZtM/7/ ---

I had the data attributes updating in the function (bad practise).
THe function for changing the elements is separate now from the interaction, so you can clean up the code as you wish. :)

Answer (score -1):

The local variable state gets destroyed every time the event is finished. 
If you want to preserve the state, you will have to put an attribute in your link using **attr()**.

Here is an update to your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremejazz/9GZtM/8/):

```
var favourites = function(action, trgt){
    $(trgt).on(action, function(e){
        var state = 0;

        if($(this).attr('data-state'))
            state=$(this).attr('data-state');


        if(state == '0'){

            thistrgt = $(e.currentTarget);
            thistrgt.css('opacity', '0.6');
            thistrgt.removeClass('favourites');
            thistrgt.addClass('favouriteschangestate');
            thistrgt.text('Saving to favourites');
            thistrgt.attr('data-state','1');
            setTimeout(function(){
                thistrgt.css('opacity', '1');
                thistrgt.text('Saved!');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    thistrgt.text('Remove from favourites');
                },2000);
            }, 2000);
        }else if(state == '1'){

            thistrgt = $(e.currentTarget);
            thistrgt.css('opacity', '0.6');
            thistrgt.removeClass('favouriteschangestate');
            thistrgt.addClass('favourites');
            thistrgt.text('Removing from favourites');
            thistrgt.attr('data-state','0');
            setTimeout(function(){
                thistrgt.css('opacity', '1');
                thistrgt.text('Removed!');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    thistrgt.text('Add from favourites');
                },2000);
            }, 2000);
        }
        return false;
    });

}


favourites('click', '.favourites');
```

Here I stored the click state in an attribute for your link called **data-state**

For more info about using attr(), you can check this: 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: this is great! i didnt know you could use attr() like that, exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry about the return false, I just edited the existing code by adding the attribute change.

Comment: oh dear! that's no good! it's going all crazy! is this because the event stops when i've clicked on another element? but it seems to be locking up still.